# WebBrowser Control continue script execution without script error warning box

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have to call 3rd party CRM system. There are some issues in their javascript code, but webpage functions correctly in IE9.

If I have ScriptErrorsSuppressed set to false I will get error message - "An error has occurred in this script on this page" and at bottom - "Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?"

If I click "Yes" web page will work correctly, "No" on other hand will not bind jquery correctly to objects.

If I set ScriptErrorsSuppressed to true, there will be no error message, however this will stop executing script and web page will not work correctly.

IE9 can display script errors, but keep on executing script. Is there a way to emulate same behaviour?

- I have tried all solutions propoused in stack overflow, but they stop script executing
- Web browser control runs in IE9 mode, I set registry value to force IE9

Thank you
-Maigais

Answer (score -1):

We have almost similar tasks. I tried everything including `WebBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true`. And this was not what I was looking for because all JavaScripts stopped working after an exception has appeared.
But the next one worked for me:

```
    public PageWithWebBrowser()
    {
            WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += OnWebBrowserDocumentCompleted;
            WebBrowser.Navigate("http://www.example.com");             
    }

    private void OnWebBrowserDocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            WebBrowser.Document.Window.Error += OnWebBrowserDocumentWindowError;
    }

    private void OnWebBrowserDocumentWindowError(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementErrorEventArgs e)
    {
            //Suppresses a dialog and continues running scripts on the page
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

As you can see I use `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control for that, may be it is going to work with WPF WebBrowser control.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but I'm still receiving script error popups. Any ideas?
http://imgur.com/aqIKLe3